# How do you add a private registry to docker?

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I'm new to Docker. I have installed Docker version : 20.10.15 and am trying to download images from one of our vendor sites.
While I was able to download images earlier, now I get the below error :

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
cmd : **docker pull containers.XXX.com/bmc/lpade:kubectl-latest**
Error response from daemon: Head "https://containers.XXX.com/v2/bmc/lpade/manifests/kubectl-latest": unauthorized: unable to get identity token from basic auth credentials: invalid grant: invalid authentication credentials given
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

May I know what is causing this error? Also I would like to know how this repo was working earlier , (as this is not a docker hub repo) how does docker knows that there is a private registry?

Comment: Initial configuration was done by another team member who moved to another team and  difficult to get response :)

Comment: Are you logged in? `docker login containers.XXX.com`